# Why x-google-acl header default is different from object ACL value?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, acl

[The list of supported values for x-google-acl](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference-headers#xgoogacl) header does not contain all of the [Bucket/Object ACL values](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#predefined-acl). Moreover, the default value for x-google-acl is `private` while default new bucket/object ACL value is `project-private`.

In my specific use case I'am uploading objects to google-cloud-storage using one specific service account X ([using this plugin](https://github.com/Byclosure/google-storage-upload)). Then I'm creating SignedURLs using another service account Y (belonging to the same google project).

My requirement is to upload the objects with `project-private` ACL so that account Y gets READ access for the newly uploaded objects.

The problem is that x-google-acl seams not supporting `project-private` ACL value.

Is there any other way of setting programmatically this ACL value while uploading a new object?

Comment: I think this may be a documentation omission; I tested and project-private works with x-goog-acl.

Comment: Thanks @TravisHobrla, I'll reply when I test it, just assumed the docs was correct as it explicitly enumerates the "Valid Values".

Comment: Did you ever find a solution, @OleksandrKruk?

Comment: Sorry @pdoherty926 can't remember details now. But we definitely followed the approach I described here to store those objects so we must have found the right configs at the time.